# Change font color javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts

I have this code.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > a.top -80) {
        $(".introHeader").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".introHeader").stop().fadeOut();
    }
```

Now i want to change the font color of the text in the div called: introHeader.
So:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > a.top -80) {
        $(".introHeader").fadeIn();
        // Change font color.
    } else {
        $(".introHeader").stop().fadeOut();
```

How can i fix this,

```
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > a.top -80) {
        $(".introHeader").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById('introHeader').color = '#999999';
    } else {
        $(".introHeader").stop().fadeOut();
```

Does'nt work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > a.top -80) {
        $(".introHeader").fadeIn();
        // Change font color.
        $(".introHeader").attr('style', 'color: #999999;');
    } else {
       ...
    }
```

It should be noted there's better ways to do this. Use a CSS class to better refine the child selectors, and then use `.addClass('className')`

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it, do you have a way to slowly change the color, with this method?

Comment: Use CSS transitions, combined with the `.addClass()` method. This should get you started: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: Fixed it with this     if ($(this).scrollTop() > b.top -300) {
         $(".introMessage").attr('style', 'transition: color 1s ease; color: #D8D8D8;');
    } else {
  $(".introMessage").attr('style', 'transition: color 1s ease; color: transparent;');
    }

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".introHeader").css('color', '#999').fadeIn();
```

You're already using jquery. Might as well make use of the css method.

And your sample is not working because color is not a property. You would have to use `style.color`

```
document.getElementById('introHeader').style.color = '#999999';
```